# How to get the public key length out of parsed x509 certification in nodejs

Tags: node.js, certificate

Newbie to x509 certifications. Working with node-js and with the most (seems like) tool to create and parse certificates - **node-forge**.
I'm trying to figure out how to get the reliable public key length and the signature hash algorithm (SHA)
out of the certificate which was created based on the certificate data. I'm getting a binary code from a .cert file and trying to parse it and get the mentioned above data. See my basic code: (the cert is the object that represent the certification)

```
let certificateContent = file.replace('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----', '').replace('-----END CERTIFICATE-----', '').trim();
certificateContent = Buffer.from(certificateContent.toString(), 'binary').toString('base64').toString().split(/(.{64})/).filter(x => x).join('\r\n');
let derData = forge.util.decode64(certificateContent);
let cert = forge.pki.certificateFromAsn1(forge.asn1.fromDer(derData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the modulus length (n) and therefore the public key length from a certificate .pem file using the convenient certificateFromPem function that forge exposes.

We can also get the signature Object Id, which we can lookup here: http://www.oid-info.com/.

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
const fs = require('fs');

function getCertificatePublicKeyBitLength(pemFile) {
    const certificate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(fs.readFileSync(pemFile));
    return certificate.publicKey.n.bitLength();
}
function getCertificateSignatureObjectId(pemFile) {
    const certificate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(fs.readFileSync(pemFile));
    return certificate.signatureOid;
}

console.log("Bit length: ", getCertificatePublicKeyBitLength('cert.pem'));
console.log("Certificate Signature Object Id: ", getCertificateSignatureObjectId('cert.pem'));
```

I've tested this by creating certs using openssl like so (a 4096-bit key here):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Comment: Thanks - it worked. BTW - it can be done also when parsing from DER format

Comment: Do you know what is the property\attribute that points out what is the signature hash algorithm (SHA) which was used ?

Comment: The certificate has a signatureOid property, in this case '1.2.840.113549.1.1.11', this corresponds to SHA256withRSA (I believe). So one would have to write a lookup function for this, perhaps using http://www.oid-info.com/.

Comment: I've added a getCertificateSignatureObjectId function which returns the object id for the signature hash algorithm used.

Comment: How to get the length for ECDSA ones ?